# Running commands as another user on their machine via ssh?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, sudo, tcsh

As part of my normal workflow I ssh into another user's machine, switch user to them, run a command, then exit out to my own machine again:

```
ssh hostname
sudo su user
runcommand
exit
exit
```

Is there a way to cut this down to a single line command? e.g.

```
ssh --someflags "runcommand"
```

I have tried this but get prompted for the other user's password which I do not have:

```
sudo ssh user@hostnme "runcommand"
```

Comment: Something like `ssh myaccount@somehost "su -u <user> -c <command>"` wouldn't work?

Comment: You could always publish your key into their authorized_keys file.  Then you can connect to using that users account directly.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do you have a user on all of the remote computers? I guess this should work, but im not sure i understand your setup correctly.

> ssh youruser@hostname "sudo -u remoteuser runcommand"

Comment: And how exactly does this address the Esker's problem?

Comment: Yeah, I misread. Updated the answer.

Comment: With a bit of tweaking, that worked, thanks. `ssh -t hostname "sudo su user -c runcommand"`

Answer (score 3):

It's often the case that a terminal is required as well. The following should work in this case:

```
commands='cd myfolder;ls -l'

ssh -ttt "youruser@remotehost" "sudo -u remoteuser sh -c ${commands}"
```

Comment: interesting:  using `... sh -c ...` works for me; but `... bash -c ....` does not and evaluates a chained command partly as the original user.